# Error in tmap_save: object 'tm' not found

Tags: tmap

When I try to save my plot as an HTML file, I got this error:

```
Error in `+.tmap`(e1 = tm, e2 = do.call("tm_layout", args)) : object 'tm' not found
```

Here is my code:

```
tm_shape(countries_spdf) +
  tm_grid(n.x = 11, n.y = 11) +
  tm_fill(col = "population", style = "quantile")  +
  tm_borders(col = "burlywood4")

# Save a static version "population.png" [success]
tmap_save(filename = "population.png")

# Save an interactive version "population.html" [fail]
tmap_save(filename = "population.html")
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try two things:

1. run everything without the call to **tmap_save(filename = "population.png")**.
2. Assign the map to an object.

   ```
    Map <- tm_shape(countries_spdf) +
     tm_grid(n.x = 11, n.y = 11) +
     tm_fill(col = "population", style = "quantile")  +
     tm_borders(col = "burlywood4")

    tmap_save(tm = Map, filename = "population.html")
   ```